# Why does GHC produce the following kind error message?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Given the following program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader

newtype AppM a = AppM (ReaderT Int IO a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader)
```

The `MonadReader` deriving declaration should be `MonadReader Int`. GHC produces the following error message:

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘MonadReader’
Expected kind ‘* -> ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Prim.Constraint’,
  but ‘MonadReader’ has kind ‘*
                              -> (* -> *) -> ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Prim.Constraint’
In the newtype declaration for ‘AppM’
```

This error message is confusing to me. The kind of `MonadReader` is `* -> (* -> *) -> GHC.Prim.Constraint`, as the error message states, which makes sense. However, the error message states that it *expects* kind `* -> GHC.Prim.Constraint`, despite the fact that `MonadReader Int` is actually of kind `(* -> *) -> GHC.Prim.Constraint`.

Given that kinds `*` and `* -> *` do not match, this error message feels not only misleading to me, but actually incorrect. Is this a bug, or am I overlooking something in this error message?

Comment: Looks like a bug with error messages and generalized newtype deriving to me. You could open a ticket on [Trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc).

Comment: Weird. I'd try standalone deriving to check whether it makes any difference.

Comment: I've opened a ticket here: http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tikhon Jelvis said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172590/why-does-ghc-produce-the-following-kind-error-message#comment65688554_39172590), this was a bug. Alexis King opened [this ticket](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12546), which was closed as fixed four months ago.